# Вывод оношений Vue Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

В Laravel просто можно вывести комментарии к посту (предварительно прописав отношения)

```
@foreach($posts as $key => $post)
    @foreach($post->comments as $key => $comment)
        <span class="info">{{ $comment->title}}</span>
    @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

А как ту же запись вывести во Vue.js ?

Comment: Передать сразу все данные компоненту. Или внутри компонента стучаться по api через axios, например, получать данные и выводит их. Laravel на сервере работает, а vue - это обычный фронт, js.

Comment: [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)